# Can you take in a function as a parameter for a method in another class?

Tags: python

```
def hourlylist():
    newlist = []
    for Employee in employeeobject():
            if Employee.classification == "1":
                newlist.append(Employee.hourly)
    return newlist




class Hourly(Classification): #classification is parent class
    def __init__(self,rate,hourly): #list of hours worked
        self.hourly = hourly
        self.rate = rate
    def set_pay(hourlylist()): #hoursworked as parameter
        print(hourlylist())
```

So I have this list from the function hourly list at the top. What I am trying to do is take in the function as a parameter for my set_pay method. Is this possible? Would I be able to call that function in the set_pay method as a parameter and call it inside of the method?

Thanks

Comment: It can be done, but I don't understand what problem you hope to solve by doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hourlylist():
    newlist = []
    for Employee in employeeobject():
            if Employee.classification == "1":
                newlist.append(Employee.hourly)
    return newlist




class Hourly(Classification): #classification is parent class
    def __init__(self,rate,hourly): #list of hours worked
        self.hourly = hourly
        self.rate = rate
    def set_pay(hourlylist): #hoursworked as parameter
        print(hourlylist)
```

but this will print the code for hourlylist if you want to execute why you are taking it as a parameter simply run it like below

```
def hourlylist():
    newlist = []
    for Employee in employeeobject():
            if Employee.classification == "1":
                newlist.append(Employee.hourly)
    return newlist




class Hourly(Classification): #classification is parent class
    def __init__(self,rate,hourly): #list of hours worked
        self.hourly = hourly
        self.rate = rate
    def set_pay(self): #hoursworked as parameter
        newlist = hourlylist() # to get newlist from function
```

make sure the hourlylist is defined before this class